# Recent First Answers from New Users on Old Questions

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, answers, new-users

A few of the reviews I've recently carried out have included first answers from new users, that have been on old questions (ie more than a few months old).

They have often been very low quality or repeated (not quite plagiarised) answers, or not answered the question, or all of the above, and I wonder if they are sock puppet accounts trying to be non-obviously answering questions from a parent user. Nobody would see them if they didn't appear in the 'First Posts' review queue.

I've flagged these answers if appropriate, but it all seems a bit odd to me.

Here's a few examples;

- ["android update sdk" on headless linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157089/android-update-sdk-on-headless-linux/26225849#26225849)
- [Playing audio file while I download it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188156/playing-audio-file-while-i-download-it/26225889#26225889)
- [Remove scroll bar from div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750430/remove-scroll-bar-from-div/26210570#26210570)
- [Mailchimp's $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true) causing conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599084/mailchimps-mcj-jquery-noconflicttrue-causing-conflict/26189196#26189196) (answer deleted, but obviously mods can see)
- [Extract translation phrases from Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815805/extract-translation-phrases-from-magento/26064282#26064282) (answer also deleted)

Is this a problem that others who have reviewed come across? Is there anything we can do about it?

Comment: I see this all the time. I usually vote to delete them. On extremely popular questions where there is a lot of passerby upvoting, I'll drop it in chat to help delete them before they can get voted out of delete-able territory.

Comment: All 10K users can see these late answers to old questions (even after they go through the review queue). There's a feed in the moderator tools section.