# How to review answers from new users that add no information?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues

I've come upon this answer during my reviews: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30774407/ and I noticed that the other answers says the same information with additional help so the new answer is pure noise (in my opinion). So I feel like flagging it but I'm not sure what flag would be appropriate. Would "very low quality" be appropriate here?

I've read this [Recent First Answers from New Users on Old Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272964/recent-first-answers-from-new-users-on-old-questions) question but it doesn't say how I should flag it (since I don't have the reputation to delete it directly).

Comment: Look at the timestamps -- that answer, although of lower quality, actually predates the other one.

Comment: Like Frédéric mentioned, the low quality answer was the fastest gun. However, it's low quality. I'd downvote it and move on.

Comment: Well actually I didn't see the other answer was actually made after. There's only a 2 minutes difference and I admit I didn't check.

Comment: If the answer is right I think no flag is appropriate here.You can downvote it or leave a comment

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Flagging has nothing to do with whether an answer is right or wrong. That's what voting is for. Flagging is strictly for posts which are in violation of the rules.

Comment: Well I thought it was a bad copy of the other answer (which happened to be later than the first one) and I was wondering if it was a reason for flagging or not.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I think I can flag answer and flaged many answers as 'low quality' or 'not as answer' and it was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a new answer, this is an earlier answer that's just...terrible (as judged by the community).

Review it like you'd review any other piece of content here.  If you think it can be saved, edit it to be saved; if you think it needs help and input from the OP, leave a comment.  I leave the decision of voting to you.

Comment: A bit difficult to "save" an answer which fails to add anything of value over other answers, without running afool of "clearly conflicts with author's intent".